# How to set size of perl Net::Telnet window to print lines more than 80 characters long

Tags: perl, telnet

The output of this script is wrapped, which I don’t want.

```
use strict;
use Net::Telnet;
system("mode 500,6000");
print "passwd: ";
my $passwd=<>;
chomp($passwd);
my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new(Host=>'linux63.blahblah.edu',Prompt=>'/l+inux63> $/');
$telnet->waitfor('/login/');
$telnet->print("myusername");
$telnet->waitfor('/Password/');
$telnet->print("$passwd\n");
$telnet->waitfor('/linux63/');
my @lines = $telnet->cmd("somecommand");
#etc
$telnet->print("logout\n");
```

This script's output is printed as:

```
This is the output of some command, has more than 80 characters in this line whic

h should not be broken
```

I want it like below, any help?

```
This is the output of some command, has more than 80 characters in this line which should not be broken
```

Below `mode` command used in script didn't help.

```
system("mode 500,6000");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Net::Telnet supports option negotiation, and [RFC 1073](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1073) is the standard for the telnet window size option. You should advertise that you `WILL NAWS`, and respond to a server request to `DO NAWS` with `IAC SB NAWS` (width) (height) `IAC SE`, where the width and the height are encoded as 16-bit big-endian (the `n` template to `pack`).